# Gridview does not comes up using custom class

Tags: android

My gridview does not renders if I am using my derived GridClass, It does render when I add GridView object to myLayout but not when I add My Grid Object/ :( .Here's is the code

```
        public class parentClass extends MyotherClass
        {
        Grid _gridV = null;

            public void createGridMenu(GridViewAdapter adp )
            {
              _gridV = (Grid) inflater.inflate(R.layout.Mygridmenu, null); 
          _gridV.setAdapter(adp);   
          MyLinearLayout.add(_gridV);   
            }
        class Grid extends GridView{

            Grid()
            {
            super(myContext);       
            }
                    @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
            {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            }
         }
        //My other methods
        }
```

Comment: I think we have to see your Mygridmenu class code to help you. (Btw it would be a good thing if your class names etc. follow the Java Naming Conventions).

Comment: i have already listed the Grid class that im using. My question here is conceptual, how do I add a Custom view (extending some view) and at the same time override the extended view's methods.For eg. my parent class has an object of my custom grid class. i want to be able to add custom object to my view heirarchy and be able to get call to overridden onMeasure(...) etc. methods of my custom view

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong constructor. Views inflated from XML require one of the constructors that take an AttributeSet in parameter.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but i did not follow, could you plz elaborate a bit, what should i do?